# How do use PlayReady on Fire TV web platform or WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, amazon-fire-tv, playready, amazon-fire-os

According to Amazon's [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/web-app-faq.html):

> **Q: Can web apps for Amazon Fire TV support digital rights management (DRM) for media playback?**
>
> The Web App Platform supports DRM for Widevine and PlayReady. For details about DRM support for native FireTV applications, see the [DRM](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/device-specifications.html) section of the Specifications for Fire TV Devices page.

However, when calling `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` from a web app (via Web App Tester) or a `WebView` (via Cordova), the request only succeeds for WideVine.

Success:

```js
navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess('com.widevine.alpha', [{
    audioCapabilities: [
        {
            contentType: 'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"',
            robustness: ''
        }
    ],
    videoCapabilities: [
        {
            contentType: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002A"',
            robustness: ''
        }
    ]
}]).then(console.log)
```

Failure:

```js
navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess('com.microsoft.playready', [{
    audioCapabilities: [
        {
            contentType: 'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"',
            robustness: ''
        }
    ],
    videoCapabilities: [
        {
            contentType: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002A"',
            robustness: ''
        }
    ]
}]).then(console.log)
```

The error's `name` is `NotSupportedError`, which means (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/requestMediaKeySystemAccess#exceptions)) PlayReady is not supported, despite Amazon's documentation stating that it is.

Answer (score 0):

PlayReady isn't supported on Fire TV `WebView`s. Only Widevine is supported.